# $\sup_{x>0}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2})=?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, optimization, derivatives

$$\sup_{x>0}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2})=?$$

I tried in the following way:

$$\sup_{x>0}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2})$$
$$=\sup_{x>0}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2\exp(\frac{1}{2})]$$
$$=\sup_{x>0}\sqrt{\frac{2e}{\pi}}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2]$$

Do i need to differentiate now and set it to zero?

$$\sqrt{\frac{2e}{\pi}}\frac{d}{dx}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2]=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2]=0$$

Then i couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $x-\frac{x^2}{2}$. Using calculus, by completing the square, you can find *where* this function reaches a maximum, and what the maximum value is.

Comment: I got the result $\sqrt{\frac{2e}{\pi}}$. But i have not understood why will i consider the function $(x-\frac{x^2}{2})$? Why not $\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2})$?

Comment: It is fine to consider the more messy function. However, your messy function has a max precisely where $x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ is biggest. We are less likely to make an error maximizing $x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ than maximizing the more complicated function. The answer to the question you asked is yes, differentiate and set the derivative equal to $0$. But the expression was complicated, so that was not clear to you. And there would have been a chance to differentiate incorrectly. With $x-\frac{x^2}{2}$, you can't miss! And yes, you got the right answer.